# How to search all files in project from text editor (IDE)?

Tags: search, ide, notepad++, sublimetext, text-editor

Which text editor allows to search all files in the project, without a need they to be opened?

For example: When I'm using Visual Studio and I open project `Ctrl+F` allows searching into all of the files in the current project. That's for `ASP.NET` projects.

I want to be able to search in my `PHP` project. I'm using `NotePad++`, but when I want to search into all the files, I need to open all of them first, and after entering the phrase to choose `Find All in All Opened Documents`. But now my project is getting bigger and bigger, and I want to be able to search into all of the files, without need all of them to be opened as a tabs.

Is there such an option in `NotePad++`? If not, can you recommend me some text editor or `IDE` that allows this type of searching in normal `PHP` project(and how that can be done)?

Comment: Just as a side note, Sublime Text also has "Find in Files..." functionality.

Comment: I use the Zeus editor and it has a macro that lets me easily search for some text in all the files in the currently open solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the function is just in front of you:
Notepad++ offers the "Find in Files..." Option in the search menu. (It is just the third tab in the usual search dialog. )

Just enter the correct filter (e.g. `*.php` or `*.*`) and use the checkboxes on the right. Most useful is "Follow current doc", which preselects the "Directory" selection. Depending on your project layout you want to enter a constant path there and also check the "In all sub-folders" option.

I really miss the ease of this notepad++ function in eclipse. For me this IS  "grep for windows". And you have also replace functionality, so this can be a "sed for windows" replacement, too.

With best regards,
Lars

Answer (score 0):

what operating system are you using?

In most Linux distros you could use the command line with something like this

```
grep -rnw ./haystack/* -e "needle"
```

Comment: I'm actually using Windows 7